# How to Label data multiple csv files as single observation in python for machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, machine-learning, neural-network

I have started a machine learning project where i am now in a phase of data prepration and labeling. In my measurement setup i have 4 sensors that are recording the data with time in milliseconds. this data is then stored as csv file as single observation. as an example, the 4 sensors mounted on different parts of the body detects the posture of the person like `"sitting"` or `"standing"`. the data is recorded for different durations, so each file is named with the posture and the time duration like `sitting_3_hours.csv`, `sitting_2min.csv` etc. Now i want to prepare the data to apply supervised machine learning approaches to classify whether the person was sitting or standing.

How to label these csv files? can i do it in python? or i have to use some kind of annotation or labeling tool? so far i have experienced with single csv file where there is one column that has all the labels like Iris flower database.

Here is as small example of how the dataset looks like.

```
 - Folder name "Sitting"
-------------Sitting_200s.csv
.............Sitting_100s_elevated.csv
-------------Sitting_200s_elevated.csv
 - Folder name "Standing"
-------------Standing_8s.csv
.............Standing_29s_elevated.csv
-------------Standing_86s_elevated.csv
```

The data in each csv file is comma seperated like this (example of Sitting_100s_elevated.txt`):

```
Time [s], Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3, Sensor4, Sensor5, Sensor6, Sensor7, Sensor8, Sensor9, Sensor10, Sensor11, Sensor12, Sensor13
+0.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.5, 833.0566, 0.49, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+1.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.5, 834.668, 0.45, 0.0, 0.0, 0.28, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+2.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.5, 831.4453, 0.38, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+3.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.5, 834.668, 0.47, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.38
+4.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.5, 829.834, 0.41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.28, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.4
+5.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.21, 28.5, 833.0566, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.38
+6.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.4, 831.4453, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+7.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.21, 28.4, 831.4453, 0.41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+8.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.21, 28.4, 834.668, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.37
+9.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.22, 28.4, 831.4453, 0.43, 0.0, 0.0, 0.36, 102037.0, 23.72, 38.39
+10.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.0, 25.21, 28.4, 833.0566, 0.44, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31, 102035.0, 23.72, 38.38
```

Here are few questions.

- Each file have complete profile of senor data which gave single observation i.e if the person is sitting or standing. do i have to create an extra 5th column in each file where i add the label?
- There will be different csv files for same class capturing different scenarios over time. do i have to concatenate all the data as one file as input to the machine learning algorithm? if yes then my other question is how to handle the time column because each time stamp for each file is recorded as milli seconds starting from 0. if no then please guide me how?

How to start doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'label' these csv files?

Comment: I mean to apply machine learning we need to import these files in python notebook and then tell what the sensors readings showing i.e. sitting or standing.

Comment: Maybe you could already show some of the code you have and also please add a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example with some sample data.

Comment: Thanks! i have added more description of the dataset and an example of one file. i haven't started to code yet as i don't know where to start, ofcourse uploading files to the jupyter note book can be done but i am more interested to know how to prepare my data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, i will try to put more code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly... yes, you can use Python for this.

You can use Python to navigate through the different folders, and/or check if the file has 'Sitting' or 'Standing' in its name to classify them differently.

You can also read your `csv` files using `pandas`.

With the example that you gave, you can use the following to produce a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sitting_100s_elevated.csv',lineterminator='+', index_col=0)
```

```
df

    Sensor1     Sensor2     Sensor3     Sensor4     Sensor5     Sensor6     Sensor7     Sensor8     Sensor9     Sensor10    Sensor11    Sensor12    Sensor13
Time [s]                                                    
0.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.50   833.06  0.49    0.00    0.00    0.31    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
1.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.50   834.67  0.45    0.00    0.00    0.28    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
2.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.50   831.45  0.38    0.00    0.00    0.31    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
3.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.50   834.67  0.47    0.00    0.00    0.31    102,037.00  23.72   38.38
4.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.50   829.83  0.41    0.00    0.00    0.28    102,037.00  23.72   38.40
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
6.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.40   831.45  0.46    0.00    0.00    0.31    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
7.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.21   28.40   831.45  0.41    0.00    0.00    0.25    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
8.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.21   28.40   834.67  0.40    0.00    0.00    0.25    102,037.00  23.72   38.37
9.00    0.00    0.09    0.00    25.22   28.40   831.45  0.43    0.00    0.00    0.36    102,037.00  23.72   38.39
10.00   0.00    0.09    0.00    25.21   28.40   833.06  0.44    0.00    0.00    0.31    102,035.00  23.72   38.38

11 rows × 13 columns
```

(If you do not wish to have the first column as index, you can remove the `index_col=0` from the code above.)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more of a Data prepration then a python code. if you just see this csv file should i make another column after sensor13 to indicate the outcome that is "Sitting" as class let say 0 for sitting and 1 for "standing". do i have to add this lable to each row? if yes then do i have to do it for all the other csv files for "standing"?

Comment: But since this is the **Sitting**_100s...' csv file, won't all these values be **0**?

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. these are sensor values they can not be 0's i am talking about the outcome that should be use for training and testing when the machine learning algos will be applied

Comment: @Hussain "*my question is more of a Data prepration then a python code*" - please notice that SO is about *programming* questions, and not ones about methodology; see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: OK, thanks! i will try my question to be clearer.